# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following - Content Security Policy directive with chrome apps based on react

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So I have been trying to create a chrome app and I want to use react the challenge is I get this error on the `index.html`

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following - 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: 'wasm-eval'".
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-9FNznTbTR9eE9FijYZd1Nv38yEwqoWN7cvqBZ2tRRJs='), 
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Before I edited the question I was recommended answers here [onclick or inline script isn't working in extension][1] which is basically to remove all javascript in the `index.html`

The challenge here is the `index.html` am using is generated when I run `npm run build` or `yarn run build`

So is there a way I can make react build without the inline javascript?

Comment: So don't use inline script create an external file and link the file to it.

Comment: But then the `index.html` is created automatically when I build the react project (`yarn build`) ?